# How to convert array to matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to pick col of A(5*7) whose index is in C and calculate its inverse. However the B here is 5*1 array rather than a square matrix. How can I achieve it?

```
A = [1 2 1 0 0 0 0;
    1/3 1 0 1 0 0 0;
     4  1 0 0 1 0 0;
     -4 2 0 0 0 1 0;
     -6 2 0 0 0 0 1]
C = [3 4 5 6 7]'

B = [A[:,i] for i in C]
x = inv(B)*b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively to what Ultima Ratio suggests you can simply write:

```
B = A[:, C]
```

(for this to work `C` should be a column vector)

Additionally in this case it would be better to simply define `C` as:

```
C = 3:7
```

or

```
C = [3,4,5,6,7]
```

*EDIT*: In your code:

```
C = [3 4 5 6 7]'
```

is a 5x1 matrix not a vector. In order to convert it to a vector write `vec(C)`. So `A[:, vec(C)]` will give you a matrix.

Comment: In this case B would become 3-d array. Is there good way to convert it to 2-d? I'm quite new to Julia :)

Comment: Sorry - I will make my answer more precise. `C` has to be a column vector (I have added an edit).

Comment: Yeah it works. It's interesting. I have to check the differences between vector and array

Comment: The difference is that a matrix has two dimensions. And both of them "get into" the index. If an array has dimension `5x1` then value `5` goes as a second index an value `1` goes as a third index. That is why you get a three dimensional array when you write `A[:, C]` as a result with third dimension having length 1.

Answer (score 1):

1. b ist not defined. What is it?
2. The B works by a vector of the slice intended: `C = vec([3 4 5 6 7])`
3. then create a 5x5 Array with the dimensions 5x5:  `B = [A[y,i] for i in C,y in 1:5]`
4. inverse the matrix `B` (which is identical to itsself in this example) multiplied by  (small) `b` should work.
   my REPL:

> ```
> julia> B = [A[y,i] for i in C,y in 1:5]
> 5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
>  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
>
> julia> x=inv(B)
> 5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
>  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
>  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
> ```

Comment: b is just a vector.Thank you. It works! But B = [A[y:,i] for i in C,y in 1:5] in 3. should be B = [A[y,i] for i in C,y in 1:5], just a ":" more